# Gatsby build fails due to style-loader error

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm checking out Gatsby for the first time and worked up a little example page and when I go to build, I get the error `WebpackError: The style-loader cannot be used in a non-browser environment` coming from one of the packages I am using (and created) [react-card-flipper](https://github.com/factor1/react-card-flipper/blob/master/ReactCardFlipper.js).

There are some styles that the component needs and are imported in the main JS file for the component:

`import './ReactCardFlipper.css';`

I understand that the build is failing because it doesn't have a place to inject the CSS from the npm module, but how do I support this in my Gatsby environment? I know I could write a plugin, but is that the work around every time? I feel it would be kind of hindering to have to write a plugin for any npm module that imports CSS. Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks!